# package development tools

Tags: software-recommendation, application-development, packaging, deb

I have some source code, I would like to make into Debian packages for Ubuntu. its been quite some times since I made packages, and I am wondering if there are any really great tools out there to help me get this done.

Comment: You need more detail.  What language are you programming in?  Do you want a link to the packaging docs as an answer?  If not you should really specify and language specific packing methods you're using.  For example, pip is super-easy to convert to debian.

Comment: I have a lot of perl, tcl, wish and bash scripts and a binary that is compiled perl. I want to know if there are tools to make the process of making a debian package easier. and what those tools are. I want feedback from ppl who use those tools, and actually develop / deploy software. My programs will run, dependent on architecture, but entirely from their own folders, or where ever someone says to save data. Ill go have a look at pip and equivis. Last time I made debian packages, I found making the package compliant very difficult. So i figured to ask this time.

Comment: ok then debuild looks cool, and its sub-process lintain, is what i was using in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For very simple packages, you can use [equivs](http://wiki.debian.org/Packaging/Files). Otherwise, take a look at [this guide](http://wiki.debian.org/IntroDebianPackaging) and go through the [packaging tutorial](http://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial).